# iPad size class not showing iPhone size call elements and constraints iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, size-classes

I've a project where pervious developer has built whole app UI in universal storyboard, but has only added UI elements and constraints for iPhone size class.
So when I run app on iPad it shows nothing. Storyboard also not showing anything for iPad size classes when I change it from iPhone to iPad using this:
[image]

I found a way to add UI elements to iPad size classes by installing it to universal size classes by clicking **Installed** button:

[image]

And can add constraints using this:

[image]

But I need do this for each and every UI element and every constraint. Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: AFAIK, using storyboard this is the only way to adapt same UI for different devices. You can check the wwdc talking about it https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/

Answer (score 0):

You can decide to have a constraint installed for all sizes or not installed at all, or you can specify for which sizes you want the constraints to be installed, but then you need to choose the ones yourself. You can shift or command select several at once and then set the installed properties for all the selected ones together.